# Laravel call controller based upon query string or post variables

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating APIs for an app. Now app developer wants me to create a fixed base url and pass the ROUTE NAME (Which will point to controller function) as POST variable. Example:

> http://example.com/Api

and POST variables like:

```
action=>'ROUTE_NAME'
```

But in laravel we can define the routes based upon the url parts as:

> http://example.com/Api/ROUTE_NAME

I have tried using a single controller and loading the other controllers based upon SWITCH statements. But that doesn't seem to be a standard practice as i need to add switch condition every time I'll create a new API. Also middleware will not work on the loaded controllers dynamically.
Is there a way in laravel to achieve this? I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: use prefix in routes

Comment: @GauravRai "Api" is already a prefix. what i need is a fix url which is http://example.com/Api  for all the APIs and load controller based upon action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#introduction) that listens on the `/Api` route, which gets the `ROUTE_NAME` from the `$request`, then you could use the `Route()` helper function to find the url of that named route, then redirect the request to that route.

Something like:

```
// Generating ROUTE_NAME url...
$url = route($request->route_name);

// Redirect to that route...
return redirect()->route($url);
```

Obviously you'll need to add code to handle if it doesn't find a route etc, maybe return a json response back with a proper error code etc.